# Custom order for elements on Admin Sonata left sidebar

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, knpmenubundle

I'm trying to make the left side to have a custom order (not alphabetical). I have more Bundles and for each bundle I have a custom `services.yml`. In each .yml I have the order that I want, but Sonata makes a custom order (A-Z) for each group. How it's possible to give a current index order ? I don't want to put all code into `app/config/services.yml`

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: currencies.yml }
    - { resource: '@XYZBundle/Resources/config/services.yml' }
```

**XYZBundle/Resource/config/services.yml content:**

```
services:
    xyz.admin.entity.one:
        class: XYZBundle\Admin\EntityAdmin_1
        arguments: [~, XYZBundle\Entity\Entity_1,  AppBundle:CRUD]
        tags:
            -
                name: sonata.admin
                manager_type: orm
                label:  Entity One
                audit: true
        public: true
    xyz.admin.entity.two:
        class: XYZBundle\Admin\EntityAdmin_2
        arguments: [~, XYZBundle\Entity\Entity_2,  AppBundle:CRUD]
        tags:
            -
                name: sonata.admin
                manager_type: orm
                label:  Entity Two
                audit: true
        public: true
    xyz.admin.entity.three:
        class: XYZBundle\Admin\EntityAdmin_3
        arguments: [~, XYZBundle\Entity\Entity_3,  AppBundle:CRUD]
        tags:
            -
                name: sonata.admin
                manager_type: orm
                label:  Entity Three
                audit: true
        public: true
```

And **app/config/config.yml**

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
       groups:
          loan.admin:
              label: Custom XYZ
              icon: '<i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>'
              items:
                  - xyz.admin.entity.one
                  - xyz.admin.entity.two
                  - xyz.admin.entity.three
```

This is how it looks. (Confidential entity names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        # default global templates
        layout:  SonataAdminBundle::layout.html.twig
    title_logo: images/logo.png
    title: Your title
    dashboard:
        groups:
            identifier.for.this.group:
                label:           Your Label
                icon:            '<i class="fa fa-globe"></i>'
                items:
                    - sonata.admin.service_name
```

The service is the standard one for sonata

```
sonata.admin.service_name:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\YourSonataAdminClass
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: "Your Label" }
    arguments:
        - ~
        - AppBundle\Entity\AsociatedEntity
        - ~
```

Comment: Ok, I'll use this. Thank you !

Comment: But now I have another problem. I added a new import (with all services) and I tried to do what you said, but I get this error now: `Unrecognized options "0, 1, 2" under "sonata_admin.dashboard.groups.custom"`

Comment: Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Without the complete yml I can't help you. Please post it

Comment: Solved. I didn't need - before label, icon, items etc.

Comment: Good!! I was not able to find a mistake on your code.

Comment: @GasKa if I have helped you could you mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 0):

I've order my menu group like that:

->firstly , you should have a specific group name that is easy to remember (dashboard, bill, ....) and make your configuration in **config/services.yaml**:

```html
....
    App\Admin\OrderAdmin:
        arguments: [~, App\Entity\Order, App\Controller\ActionAdminController]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: dashboard, label: Orders }
    App\Admin\RequestAdmin:
        arguments: [~, App\Entity\Request, App\Controller\ActionAdminController]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: dashboard,label: Request }
    App\Admin\clientAdmin:
        arguments: [~, App\Entity\Client,  App\Controller\ActionAdminController]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: dashboard,label: "client" }
    App\Admin\BillAdmin:
        arguments: [~, App\Entity\Bill, App\Controller\ActionAdminController]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: bill, label: 'Bill clients' }
        public: true
    App\Admin\DailyBillAdmin:
        arguments: [~, App\Entity\DailyBill, App\Controller\ActionAdminController]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: bill, label: 'Daily Bills' }
    App\Admin\OlderBillAdmin:
        arguments: [~, App\Entity\OlderBill, App\Controller\ActionAdminController]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: bill, label: 'Older Bills clients' }
        public: true
    App\Admin\ConfigurationAdmin:
        arguments: [~, App\Entity\Configuration, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm,group: configuration, label: 'Configuration Taxes' }
    App\Admin\UserAdmin:
        arguments: [~, App\Entity\User, App\Controller\ActionAdminController]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm,group: users, label: 'User Management' }
.....
```

and after you can easily order your groupe name like this in **config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml** like:

```html
sonata_admin:
    title: 'Your Title'
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            - { type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list, position: left }
        groups:
            dashboard:
                label: DASHBOARD
            bill:
                label: BILLS
            configuration:
                label: CONFIGURATIONs
            users:
                label: USERS
            ......
```

and if you want to reorder the item into the group or not into the group you can use items options . here is the documentation for that : [documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/cookbook/recipe_knp_menu.html#)